# doe the python command os.terminal_size work on macs

Tags: python

At this point I feel like I know the answer, but I just need someone to tell me.

Is the os.terminal_size command on python unusable for mac users? Would love to implement this command into a little project I am doing, but can seem to get it to work. On the off chance it's my syntax here's my little testing script:
`os.terminal_size(60, 60)`

And I keep getting "TypeError: constructor requires a sequence"

Comment: You need to pass in a list-like object is what the error is saying. A tuple would work: `os.terminal_size((60, 60))`.

Comment: Read the documentation, it's a subclass of `tuple()`. So the arguments are similar to the arguments to `tuple()` -- it requires an iterable, not separate arguments.

Comment: However, it doesn't actually seem to do anything. It doesn't resize the terminal window, and calling `os.get_terminal_size()` after it returns the old size.

Comment: I also tried this on Linux, calling it doesn't change anything there, either.

Comment: It's not a function for changing the terminal size, it's just a class for holding the value returned by `os.get_terminal_size()`.

Comment: see https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.terminal_size it is indeed a class to hold the terminal size and does not change anything about the terminal.

Comment: Ok this clear it up! Does anyone know of a good way to format the terminal from within the python code?